# Wordpress Alternate Mobile Version Logo

Tags: html, css, wordpress

on my WordPress Website I want to display another logo on the mobile version than on the desktop version. I manage to achieve this using the following code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 981px) {
  #logo {
    content: url("URL OF MOBILE LOGO");
  }
}
```

This works pretty decent but now I have big problem. The link for this logo is missing. Usually the logo should link to "/home/" However, it does not.

I tried to add the link in the header via html with the following code:

`<a id="logo" href="/"><span>Return to Home Page</span></a>`

This just clones the mobile logo and puts in above or below the header. But with a link :/ ...

Could you guys please help me out on this one :)

Best regards,

Marius

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery append() to achieve this.

Final Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 981px) {
      .mobileLogo a:before {
        content: 'MobileLogo';
        display: block;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="desktopLogo">DesktopLogo</div>
    <!-- append mobileLogo here -->
  </header>
  <!-- jquery cdn -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- custom script -->
  <script>
    $('header').append('<div class="mobileLogo"><a href="/"></a></div>');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Bibek, where would you recommend to enter this code? As this is HTML Code, I cannot simply enter it in my CUSTOM CSS Theme option field.

Comment: I believe that you are using Jquery for your WP site. If so, add that <script> in your custom js file. Then, try to append 'mobileLogo' wherever you want depending on your structure.